# Inserting two columns at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert, last-insert-id

I am trying to insert into two connected tables.

Table 1:   workouts(id, ...)  The id auto increments.

Table 2:   customWorkouts(id, workoutID, ....)

But the thing is, the two tables are connected, customWorkouts.workoutID references workouts.id.

My question is, how can I execute two consequtive queries, the first creating a new workout and the second creating a related customWorkouts? How can I make the created customWorkouts instantly connected to the workout that I just created?

Comment: Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the second query to get the auto increment ID that was created in the first query.

Comment: That 100% solves it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`last_insert_id()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html):

```
insert into workouts(col1, col2) values('foo', 'bar');
insert into custom_workouts(workout_id, col1) values(last_insert_id(), 'baz');
```

Note that this requires you to run both queries on the same connection:

> For `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client.

Comment: @BassamKaddoura: yes, this is safe in a multi-connection environnement. See the quote from the documentation that I added to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just read the post Barmar linked, thank you! ^^